# OO Design. How to name objects with the same name?

Tags: oop, object

So, maybe a bit of a silly question, but say I have several models in a MVC pattern that are named "Item" e.g

```
Forms     -> Item
Orders    -> Item
Settings  -> Item
Catalogue -> Item
```

Is the solution to name the item as follows?

```
Forms     -> FormItem
Orders    -> OrderItem
```

Or is it to namespace item under it's parent so it will be

```
Form.item
Order.item
```

etc..

Comment: What is the meaning of a 'Form Item'?

Comment: It was an example, but the main place I have the issue is for example in an e-commerce system I have items in the shopping cart, and items in the catalogue, these are different so I need more than one "item" in the system

Comment: I think both suggestions are fine (append name and namespace/inner class, though I would use an uppercase `I` after `.`). What language are you using? I think that is relevant.

Comment: You seem to have started with bad naming - `Item` is much too generic a name for an object.

Comment: Some alternative suggestions: Forms Item -> Form, Orders Item -> Order, Settings Item -> Setting, Catalogue Item -> Product, Shopping care Item -> ... eh ShoppingCartItem :-)

Comment: The question is more appropriate for http://programmer.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think Item is too generic, so I will work on that.  I think I will try both ways and see what presents clearer. Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do as you want, as long as your code is clear, well documented, and easy to read and maintain.

One recommendation though: Establish a naming convention in your project, and then be consistent with it.

Comment: One of the means to reaching the goal of maintainability is proper naming, and that's what the OP is trying to do. Do you have any suggestions on that matter?

Comment: @TheNail Yes, to choose a policy and then keep consistency.